# How to impersonate specific user in sharepoint foundation by code

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, impersonation

I'm trying to impersonate another user by code.. I know in Sharepoint Enterprise there's a method which uses the UserProfileManager to impersonate...

I wrote down this "trace code" without know if it is right or wrong... Can anybody suggest me if i'm doing the impersonification in the right way?

```
private static void impersonateSpecificUser(string username, SPSite site, SPWeb currentWeb)
    {
        SPUser user = currentWeb.EnsureUser(username);
        currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("", site.Url, "");
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
        HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = currentWeb;
        WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        typeof(WindowsIdentity).GetField("m_name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(wi, user.LoginName);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(wi, new string[0]);
    }
```

May it work on Sharepoint Foundation??

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [SPSite constructor override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469253.aspx) for this purpose.

The code will look something like this:

```
SPUser user = // grab the SPUser object somewhere
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost", user.UserToken))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    // do whatever you need here
  }
}
```

This will work in Foundation, too.

Comment: Simple and clean, I was just minutes away from submitting the same thing ;)

Comment: 2 questions::  1. Is SPUser password required? For example can I impersonate as any user using this code without having the users password?   2. Can this method be used to access resources on filesystem like RWEP?